Determine the matrix valued one-form in Chern connection on $(E,h)$
In Proposition 4.2.14 of Huybrechts complex geometry, it is stated that there exists a unique Hermitian connection $\nabla$ that is compatible with the holomorphic structure, known as the Chern connection.
The proposition establishes that the connection $\nabla$ takes the form $\nabla=d+A$, where $A$ is a matrix-valued one-form. The proof proceeds by determining the matrix $A$ fully. It is given that the assumption of compatibility of $\nabla$ with the Hermitian structure yields the equation:
$$ dH=A^tH+H\bar{A}, $$
where $H$ represents the Hermitian matrix of the Hermitian structure $h$. By utilizing the fact that $d=\partial +\bar{\partial}$, we have:
$$dH= \partial H +\bar{\partial}H=A^tH+H\bar{A}. $$
Huybrechts then states: "Since $\nabla$ is compatible with $\bar{\partial}$, the matrix $A$ is of type $(1,0)$. A comparison of types on both sides yields $\bar{\partial}H=H\bar{A}$."
This statement implies that $\partial H = A^tH$.
$\cdot$How do we derive the equation $\partial H = A^tH$?

You have $x+y=z+w$ with $y=w$. Therefore $x=z$. Am I missing something?

@TedShifrin the question is why $y=w$.

You quoted Huybrechts’s explanation. $A$ is a matrix of $(1,0)$-forms, and so $\bar A$ is a matrix of $(0,1)$-forms. At any rate, your question is far from clear.

@TedShifrin yes, but I don't understand why from what you wrote we get  $\partial H= A^tH$.  How applying $\partial $ is the same as $A^t$ ?

@TedShifrin  OOH! I see, it was almost trivial, it can't be $\partial H=H\bar{A}$ because $\partial$ would give a $(1,0)$-forms but  $H\bar{A}$ are $(0,1)$-forms so it has to be $\partial H=A^tH$ right ?

In principle it could be a messy combination, but compatibility with the complex structure guarantees that $A$ must be a matrix of $(1,0)$-forms. Then the rest is matching types.
